# Sqlpackage.exe not recognized

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

i am trying to run command

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"MyProject.BI.Database.MyDb.dacpac" /Profile:"Local.MyProject.BI.Database.MyDb.publish.xml" 1> Local.MyProject.BI.Database.MyDb.log 2>&1
```

But i get error

```
SqlPackage is not recognized command
```

I downloaded sqlpackage.exe and installed.

I also added it in environment variable but still i get error

I have Sql server 2019

How to fix this?

Comment: Where are you running this command? What if you use the fully qualified path? I'm guessing for whatever reason it's not finding it in the path

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i am running using command prompt

Comment: Just because you "install" a program does not mean you can run it from the command line without using complete path. The error is telling you the problem - the program is not in your path so it cannot be found. Use the complete path to the application.

Comment: If you run it fully qualified, i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\sqlpackage.exe` does it work?

Comment: and if you type `PATH` into the command line can you see the path you expect?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it works when i run from programfiles folder

Comment: So it's simply an issue with PATH. So you need to troubleshoot the _I also added it in environment variable_ bit - clearly that is not functioning. Do you see the expected path when you type `PATH` in the command line?